# Secure iframe from HTTPS solutions

Tags: security, http, rest, iframe, https

I'm working on a registration app/api that will allow for event registration/payments and I'm exploring the best options extend this to user websites. I've considered Iframes but I fear that the non secure nature of the user's site would nullify any security measures I take.

My other option may not be as user friendly but basically provide make it all work through API/Rest calls but this relies on the user's competency to setup.

Basically what I want is is to have service hosted at https://myservice.com and allow https://mywebsite.com to integrate with the app created. I'd like to have a 3 part form to register and pay for an event but the primary focus is on security.

So is my thinking completely off base? Do I need to do a lot more research? Or am I over thinking it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a question here, or are you just wanting someone to do this for you?

Comment: I'm seeking recommendations on my some what scatterbrained thoughts and concerns. Clearly I'm not expecting someone to do this for me but your concern is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: By what measure is `https://mywebsite.com` not 'secure'? It's served through HTTPS - but is the model that the end-user only trusts `myservice.com`, and not `mywebsite.com`?